# How do we minimize precision error with FP16 half precision floating point numbers

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754, half-precision-float

I have one example 50.33123 can be stored in FP32(1.8.23) format as 0x4249532E . If we convert this to binary

```
0100 0010 0100 1001 0101 0011 0010 1110
```

First bit is sign bit, which is `0` means positive number,

Next 8 bits are exponent -> 1000 0100<sub>2</sub> -> 84<sub>16</sub> -> 132<sub>10</sub>.  Exponent 132 -127 = `5`

Mantissa `1.1001 0010 1010 0110 0101 110` (23 bits)

left shift my exponent => 110010.010101001100101110<sub>2</sub> => 50.33123<sub>10</sub>

If we store same thing, in FP16(half precision format) FP16 => 1.5.10:

without rounding
1.1001 0010 10<sub>2</sub>
left shift by 5 => 110010.01010<sub>2</sub> => 50.3125<sub>10</sub>,
the error is 50.33123 - 50.3125  => 0.01873.

with rounding
1.1001 0010 11<sub>2</sub> => left shift by 5 => 110010.01011<sub>2</sub> => 50.34375<sub>10</sub>,
the error is 50.33123 - 50.34375 = -0.01252

My question is, here the error is significant.
Is there any way to reduce the error further with FP16 implementations?

Comment: I think you have reached the end of precision, no way to minimise the error any further. I.e. I am not sure I understood your question correctly. Isn't it the same as asking "how can I reduce the error of representing 257 in an unsigned byte? `257-255==2`" ? 2 is the smallest error you can get for 257 represented in an unsigned 8bit.

Comment: Can you show the kind of calculation you do on those 16bit floats? Maybe wiht a bit of math it is possible to work on a foundation of a "middle value" (working point), stored in one float and then always calculate the delta. Finally add middle value and delta and use the result for whatever.

Comment: example: float a=50.33123, b=50.33123; type fp_16 a_fp16, b_fp16; a_fp16=(fp_16) a; b_fp16=b; for(int i =0; i<1000;i++) {  out_fp16 +=  a_fp16*b_fp16; } I am seeing huge precision error in this case.

Comment: typo corrected.  out_fp32 += a_fp16*b_fp16;  a and b float values vary in my original case.. just for simplicity , I added fixed float values.

Comment: I understand that you have to store a and b in 16bit floats; the calculation result however is finally stored (and accumulated) in a 32bit float. Did you try to first convert to 32bit, then calculate purely in 32bit. Afterwards, the converted 32bit can be deleted, i.e. a and b stay 16bit stored only. I understand that this might not be the solution, but the experiment might be enlightening. Theoretically, you might accumulate (over the loop) a rather small error, letting it grow big. I actually doubt that, but for clarity and for exclusion analysis, the experiment seems worthwhile.

Comment: [I am seeing huge precision error in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450365/how-do-we-minimize-precision-error-with-fp16-half-precision-floating-point-numbe#comment75906404_44450365)  ==> What is the value of that huge precision error ?  How much error is acceptable?

Comment: when we iterate through the loop(say 1000) for the value of 50.33123 in half 16 format. It will be huge. Error has to be as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> how do we minimize precision error with FP16 half precision floating point numbers

`Fp16 => 1.5.10` explicitly stores 10 bits of precision in `fp_16`, a binary floating point format.  With the implied bit, that provides values whose [Unit in the Last Place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) is 2<sup>-10</sup> of the most significant bit.  50.33123 as a `float` has an exact value of `50.33123016357421875` or `0x1.92A65Cp+5`.  With *rounding* to minimize precision error, the closest value as `fp_16` is `50.34375` or `0x1.92Cp+5`.

OP has done this rounding for minimal error.

---

> ... the error in this case is, 50.33123 - 50.34375 = -0.01252
>   My question is, here the error is significant. is there any way to reduce the error further with FP16 implementations?

This 0.02% difference is not unexpected.  Without changing the `1.5.10` format, or saving additional values as below, this precision loss is unavoidable.

```
float a = 50.33123f;
a_fp16_upper = (fp_16) a;
a_fp16_lower = (fp_16) (a - a_fp16_upper);
```